# Excerpt in templates with single post

Tags: wordpress

In the theme, I use `get_the_excerpt` in `index.php`, where I use the loop to display the titles, excerpts, ... of several post and it works as expected. The excerpt/teaser is manually marked with the "read more" tag.

However, I also would like to use `get_the_excerpt` in `single.php` but instead of receiving only the text up to the "read more" tag, I get the first 55 words.

The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/#more-information) says:

> The `<!--more-->` quicktag will not operate and is ignored in Templates where just one post is displayed, such as single.php.

Ok, so what can I do if I want the excerpt to contain the text only up to the quicktag in `single.php`?

Comment: Just curious if you've tried the example provided in the first user-contributed note on the page you linked to? The one with `global $more; $more = 0; ....`?

Comment: @cale_b My old eyes aren't what they used to be. If you post it as an answer, I'll accepted it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you want with the built-in functionality of WordPress, utilizing the `$more` variable.

In order to show the content *before the more quicktag*, you should be able to do this on your single.php:

```
// Declare global $more (before the loop).
global $more;

while( have_posts() ) {
   // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
   $more = 0;
   // call the_post() to prepare post variables / functions
   the_post();
   // output your markup, post title, etc...
   // then this the_content() should render only the content before the more quicktag
   the_content( 'More ...' );
}
```